# Alternatives to get from Belize international airport to Belize City

Tags: buses, taxis, recommendations, belize

I know there are taxis to the city by 25 USD but think I could walk the Airport Road to the Northern Hwy (about  3 km) to get a (cheaper) bus to Belice City so I can take the ferry to the islands. Is that possible? I have seen on [Google Maps](https://www.google.com.mx/maps/dir/17.546612,-88.28887/Philip+S.W.+Goldson+International+Airport,+International+Airport+Road,+Ladyville,+Belize/@17.5464961,-88.2896041,16z/data=!4m9!4m8!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x8f5c5b3a25c47481:0x3dfeab1620160d3d!2m2!1d-88.3077692!2d17.5360677!3e2) some bus stops in the nearings but I want to be sure before walking near 2 miles and still after all needing to get a Taxi.

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Trip Advisor:](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g291968-i2338-k8813894-Getting_from_Belize_airport_to_Belize_bus_station-Belize_City_Belize_District.html)

> Yes, you can walk from airport to junction with Northern Highway and flag down a local bus headed to the bus station in the city.